# How to display a random item from an array when the user performs a click

Tags: android

I have an array with 5 elements, I want to display a random item from this list every time the user clicks the button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("item 1");
    list.add("item 2");
    list.add("item 3");
    list.add("item 4");
    list.add("item 5");
```

I tried this:

```
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(list.size());
            textview.setText(getString(index));

        }
    });
```

But I got an error on click:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: activfy.activfy, PID: 18639
                                                             android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x72
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:250)
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:336)
                                                                 at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:345)
                                                                 at activfy.activfy.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:159)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in line textview.setText(getString(index));
replace it with textview.setText(list.get(index));

Comment: oh I forgot that index is an integer. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, If it helps, you can accept it as an answer.